# Is it possible to set the where clause through a data annotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

May be this is a stupid question.

I have some model class in a Asp.Net web api 2.2 application, which implements an interface `ICountryOfOrigin`.

I need to filter records by applying where clause as shown below. I have to repeat this logic in many controllers with different models which implement `ICountryOfOrigin`.

Is it possible to move the filtering logic into a separate method and apply it to the controller action through data annotation?

My intention is to eliminate the repeating code.

Is it possible?

```
//Interface
public Interface ICountryOfOrigin
{
    string Country {get;set;}
}

//Model
public class Product : ICountryOfOrigin
{
    ..
    string Country {get;set;}
}

//Action
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    List<string> euCountries = GetEuCountries();
    Product product = _repository.Products.GetAll().Where(p=> euCountries.Contains(p.countries); // The filter is applied here
    return Ok(products);
}


//Need to achieve something like this
[EuCountriesOnly]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
  List<string> euCountries = GetEuCountries();
  Product product = _repository.Products.GetAll();
  return Ok(products);
}
```

Any experts help me on this?

Comment: _"I have to repeat this logic in many controllers with different models which implements ICountryOfOrigin."_ - that's because you shouldn't be accessing the database in your controller, but abstract that. Look into the repository pattern.

Comment: @CodeCaster  Yes I'm using a generic repository pattern. My question is about data annotation.

Comment: It doesn't look like it from your code.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is how I'm gelling products from product repository. `_repository.Products.GetAll();` (I have made slight changes in above code.)  My question is i have to repeat `_repository.Products.GetAll();` in many controllers. How can I apply where clause through DataAnnotations?

Comment: @Nkosi  Could you please provide an answer with a code example ;) ?

Comment: I would agree with @CodeCaster, your `_repository` looks more like a `DbContext` to me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would shoot anybody who would implemented it the way you want. Believe me, it's not cool at all to alter behavior of some method you're calling with an attribute you put on a calling method.

Just put the logic into an extension method on your repository type and call it a day:

```
public static class RepoExtensions
{
  private static readonly euCountries = new Country[]{};
  public static IEnumerable<ICountryOfOrigin> GetEU(this Repository repo)
  {
    return repo.Products.GetAll().Where(p=> euCountries.Contains(p.countries);
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that your repository is of type `Repository`, you'll need to put the real type instead of it.